# hillshade and slopeshade geotiffs fail to convert to new projection using gdalwarp

Tags: dem, gdalwarp, gdaldem

I'm trying to convert my three DEM products (colour, hillshade and slopeshade; the latter two generated using gdaldem) from EPSG:4326 -> EPSG:3857 using gdalwarp, via the command:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 -co "tfw=yes" {src} {dst}
```

This works fine for the colour geotiff, but the resulting hillshade and slopeshade geotiffs now appear blank.

Sample output from gdalinfo for the slopeshade geotiff is below, with links to the original and converted files at the bottom.

gdalinfo before:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: slopeshade_dem.tif
Size is 4557, 3577
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-121.460761599999998,38.583444700000001)
Pixel Size = (0.000000654597323,-0.000000654598826)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-121.4607616,  38.5834447) (121d27'38.74"W, 38d35' 0.40"N)
Lower Left  (-121.4607616,  38.5811032) (121d27'38.74"W, 38d34'51.97"N)
Upper Right (-121.4577786,  38.5834447) (121d27'28.00"W, 38d35' 0.40"N)
Lower Right (-121.4577786,  38.5811032) (121d27'28.00"W, 38d34'51.97"N)
Center      (-121.4592701,  38.5822740) (121d27'33.37"W, 38d34'56.19"N)
Band 1 Block=4557x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=4557x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

gdalinfo after:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: slopeshade_dem.tif
Size is 4088, 4105
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-13520950.132675198838115,4662178.034760829061270)
Pixel Size = (0.081230547006284,-0.081230547006284)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-13520950.133, 4662178.035) (121d27'38.74"W, 38d35' 0.40"N)
Lower Left  (-13520950.133, 4661844.583) (121d27'38.74"W, 38d34'51.97"N)
Upper Right (-13520618.062, 4662178.035) (121d27'28.00"W, 38d35' 0.40"N)
Lower Right (-13520618.062, 4661844.583) (121d27'28.00"W, 38d34'51.97"N)
Center      (-13520784.097, 4662011.309) (121d27'33.37"W, 38d34'56.19"N)
Band 1 Block=4088x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=4088x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Links to the slopeshade file before conversion (in EPSG:4326):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9safqs1hkngnasf/slopeshade_dem.tif?dl=0

Links to the slopeshade file after conversion (in EPSG:3857):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebmgnbhrzog01ui/slopeshade_dem.tif?dl=0

Comment: solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122635/how-do-i-convert-a-tif-to-epsg3857